# Dialogflow fulfillment - querying firebase with parameters from user

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am currently working on a dialogflow app for my company. I need to get our app to be able to take any name given by the user and match it to the database.

We manufacture CNC machines and we are attempting to create an application that allows the user to obtain information about their machine using their phone or google home. We have a website that allows them to give their machine a name. This name could be anything. It could be "Zodiac", or it could be "ZMachine #123". This name is stored in the database and is used to reference the machine from the dialogflow app. However, when google parses the voice input, and I get that entity in the fulfilment, I end up with "z machine number 123" or something like that, which I cannot match to the database directly. This is especially true for names that are not standard English words or names, such as a company name or something like that.

I was wondering if anyone had any resources that could point me in the right direction? I noticed that when you name smart devices in google, you can name them anything you like and it still gets it right. What are they doing in the background that allows this to take place?

Comment: if you have list of machine names you can create session entities for that

Comment: Unfortunately, the names can be changed at any time and the list is always being added to. Is there a way to dynamically link entities to names in the database?

Comment: yes thats what i am taking about, please chcek the session entities doc, every time you can fetch machine list and set it as entities

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I'll check that out.